# Kubernetes MySQL pod keeps crashing and shows Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes

I have created new docker image and added in kubernetes statefulset yaml for mysql pod. When I scaled mysql pod to 1 , it's keeps crashing and throwing message
 `unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11`

I have googled lot about this error but none of them gave a solution. Appreciate if any one help me!

[image]

Docker file:

```
FROM mysql/mysql-server
CMD [ "--max_connections=10000" ]
```

And Created MySQL YAML like below:

```
{
  "kind": "StatefulSet",
  "apiVersion": "apps/v1beta2",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "mysql-test",
    "namespace": "test",
    "selfLink": "/apis/apps/v1beta2/namespaces/test/statefulsets/mysql-test",
    "uid": "e7768a0b-faf9-11e9-a989-d8c497367e2a",
    "resourceVersion": "315823479",
    "generation": 33,
    "creationTimestamp": "2019-10-30T09:44:44Z",
    "labels": {
      "app": "mysql-test",
      "release": "mysql-test"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "replicas": 1,
    "selector": {
      "matchLabels": {
        "app": "mysql-test"
      }
    },
    "template": {
      "metadata": {
        "creationTimestamp": null,
        "labels": {
          "app": "mysql-test"
        }
      },
      "spec": {
        "volumes": [
          {
            "name": "data",
            "persistentVolumeClaim": {
              "claimName": "mysqldata"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "backup",
            "persistentVolumeClaim": {
              "claimName": "mysqlbackup"
            }
          }
        ],
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "latest",
            "image": "<Enterprise repository>/careercompass/mysql:latest",
            "ports": [
              {
                "name": "mysql",
                "containerPort": 3306,
                "protocol": "TCP"
              }
            ],
            "env": [
              {
                "name": "MYSQL_PASSWORD",
                "valueFrom": {
                  "secretKeyRef": {
                    "name": "mysql",
                    "key": "mysql-password",
                    "optional": true
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD",
                "valueFrom": {
                  "secretKeyRef": {
                    "name": "mysql",
                    "key": "mysql-root-password",
                    "optional": true
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "MYSQL_USER",
                "value": "mysql"
              },
              {
                "name": "MYSQL_DATABASE"
              }
            ],
            "resources": {
              "limits": {
                "cpu": "10",
                "memory": "10000Mi"
              },
              "requests": {
                "cpu": "200m",
                "memory": "3000Mi"
              }
            },
            "volumeMounts": [
              {
                "name": "data",
                "mountPath": "/var/lib/mysql"
              },
              {
                "name": "backup",
                "mountPath": "/var/lib/mysqlbackup"
              }
            ],
            "terminationMessagePath": "/var/lib/termination-log",
            "terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
            "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent"
          }
        ],
        "restartPolicy": "Always",
        "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30,
        "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
        "securityContext": {
          "runAsUser": 999,
          "fsGroup": 999
        },
        "schedulerName": "default-scheduler"
      }
    },
    "serviceName": "",
    "podManagementPolicy": "OrderedReady",
    "updateStrategy": {
      "type": "RollingUpdate",
      "rollingUpdate": {
        "partition": 0
      }
    },
    "revisionHistoryLimit": 10
  },
  "status": {
    "observedGeneration": 33,
    "replicas": 1,
    "currentReplicas": 1,
    "updatedReplicas": 1,
    "currentRevision": "mysql-test-68cb64885c",
    "updateRevision": "mysql-test-68cb64885c",
    "collisionCount": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't have multiple mysql server working on the same data

Comment: Could you share your YAML? Did you use Dockerfile to create this image?

Comment: @Sanjay did Kamol's answer helped you? Did you see this article: https://bobcares.com/blog/innodb-unable-to-lock-ibdata1-error-11/ ?

Comment: nope, still it is throwing same error. @PjoterS

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a little bit late, but still...
I'm not using Kubernetes, but I was having the same error.

In my case, the solution was changing one line in the docker-compose.yml file

In the volume section of the problematic container, just change

- persistent:/var/lib/mysql

For this:

- ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql

This makes a sort of share folder between the container and the external file system.

Previous to that I removed the container whit `docker prune` command and then rebuild whit `docker compose up -d` and that's it

Just remember **backup the database** first, because you will delete everything whit 'docker prune'

Answer (score 0):

If your mysql database pod is currently running, it will have an issue with your database files because its currently locked with the old pod, and it might take some time to terminate.

Scale the deployment of the pod with replicas = 0
do your change and then scale it to replicas = 1.
To find the deployment name use the below but with your namespace.

```
kubectl get deploy -n your-db-namespace
```

When you get the name of the deployment, use the below to scale the replicas=0 to unlock the files of the db.

```
kubectl scale deploy -n your-db-namespace your-db-name-deployment --replicas= 0
```

When the pods no longer appear when you do:

```
kubectl get pods -n your-db-namespace
```

Do the following by changing the replicas back to 1.

```
kubectl scale deploy -n your-db-namespace your-db-name-deployment --replicas= 1
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for answering this old comment. But I have the same problem. In my Microk8s Server, pods are restarting (no idead why) and some pods can not start again because of already hold locks by old pods. I get the same message in my mysql container. How can I tell K8S to kill the pod and wait a few seconds until it restarts it again? If I do a "kubectl delete pod", mysql is starting without problems.

Comment: get the deployment 

kubectl get deploy -n namespace

and change the replicas as instructed above to 0.

kubectl scale deploy -n the-namespace the-deployment-you-got-before --replicas= 0

 When is terminated which means it does not appear when you do:

kubectl get pods -A 

then you will be able to start it by doing the replicas=1 back again.
kubectl scale deploy -n the-namespace the-deployment-you-got-before --replicas= 1

Comment: But this does not help. I can not scale down the deployment all the time. Then I could also kill the pod manually. My current solution will be a cronjob which runs every minute and kills every pod in all namespaces which is in Error state. Is there not a solution for kubernetes which works out-of-the-box? I mean, I can not be the only one which has such a problem.